# can't convert complex to float?

Tags: python

quiero que el programa calcule un valor de F para cada ciclo for 
y que los valores de F se posicionen en la diagonal de la matriz de ceros

```
MMM = 3
PHI = numpy.zeros((MMM,MMM))

a=np.array([ 0.71,  1.63,  0.85])
b=np.array([ 0.24,  0.14, -0.03])
for k in range(0,MMM):
    F = 1j*a[k]/b[k] 
    PHI[(k),(k)] = F
```

me sale

```
can't convert complex to float
```

quiero obtener

```
[[ 2.95833333333j  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  11.6428571429j  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  28.3333333333j]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como has definid el array `PHI` (por defecto del tipo `float`) no podrás asignarle un valor complejo. Debes asegurarte que el `array` soporte este tipo de datos, la forma más sencilla es definir el [tipo](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html) al crearlo:

```
PHI = np.zeros((MMM,MMM),dtype=np.complex_)
```